# How do I permanently rename a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to build a PHP 8 / Nginx for a Laravel application. I start it successfully with docker-compse -up.

`docker ps` gives me the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE        COMMAND                   NAMES
b0e55ad98a63  laravel-app  "docker-php-entrypoi..."  laravel_docker_medium_tut_app_1
da779e8fa633  nginx:alpine "/docker-entrypoint...."  laravel_docker_medium_tut_nginx_1
```

My folder where I have the docker-compose.yml is called: *./laravel_docker_medium_tut/*.

I can rename the containers with:

```
docker rename b0e55ad98a63 laravel-api-app
docker rename da779e8fa633 laravel-api-nginx
```

docker ps now prints me the successfully renamed containers:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE        COMMAND                   NAMES
b0e55ad98a63  laravel-app  "docker-php-entrypoi..."  laravel-api-app
da779e8fa633  nginx:alpine "/docker-entrypoint...."  laravel-api-nginx
```

**Problem:**
If I now run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d` again I have the old names again: laravel_docker_medium_tut_app_1, laravel_docker_medium_tut_nginx_1 .

**My question:** How can I permanently rename the names?

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

#Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: mike
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    
 #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  #Mysl Service
      
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: The container names shouldn't usually matter.  In most cases you can use equivalent `docker-compose` commands to do operations on containers if you really need to.  You could also set the Compose project name (`docker-compose -p` option) if you wanted to affect the generated names, but it'd be entirely cosmetic.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you David! In my case, I want to give the container to someone, so I know what the container will be called if there are any questions. So less cosmetic, more pragmatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `container_name` in your `docker-compose.yaml`.